# Java Maven Clean and Build With Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, qr-code, netbeans-8

im still new in java maven and dependencies. can i ask? 
I create some project about QR code Generator with using Java Maven.
When I run my project into Netbeans, using qrgen-1.2.jar, core-2.0.jar and javase-2.0.jar. IT CAN GENERATE ANY QR CODE THAT I WANT.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4YCW.png]

But when i try to Build and Clean, it CANNOT generate my QR code in my Document/NetbeansProjects/QRcode/target/QRcode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.JR

Here my pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>QRcode</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>                       
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version> 


          <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.qrcode.QRcode</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>      
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
        <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
         </dependency>                       

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your POM, you aren't packaging your dependencies in the executable jar being generated.  This is causing your program to fail when you run it outside of the IDE.

Here's an example of how to use the Maven Assembly plugin to create an executable jar that includes your dependencies:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.qrcode.QRcode</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The output of `mvn package` will now include `target/QRcode-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, which you can see includes the classes specified by your build dependencies.

Here's a [link to the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) for the plugin.

Comment: thank you very much sir, my problem was solved. im so grateful.